# Config Transforms not applying on Web API publish

Tags: asp.net, configuration, asp.net-web-api, publish, web-config-transform

I have an ASP.NET Web API project which includes 2 config transforms:

- Web.Live.config
- Web.UAT.config

If I choose either `Live` or `UAT` configuration when publishing, the transforms are not applied on the rendered `web.config` file.

I've checked my transform configs, and the `name`, `xdt:Transform` and `xdt:Locator` are correct.

In my `web.config` I have:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="foo" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" connectionString="[main connection string]" />
</connectionStrings>
```

In my `web.Live.config` I have:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<!-- For more information on using web.config transformation visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=125889 -->

<configuration xmlns:xdt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/XML-Document-Transform">

  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="foo" 
      connectionString="[live connection string]" 
      xdt:Transform="SetAttributes" xdt:Locator="Match(name)"/>
  </connectionStrings>

  <system.web>
    <compilation xdt:Transform="RemoveAttributes(debug)" />
    <!--
      In the example below, the "Replace" transform will replace the entire 
      <customErrors> section of your web.config file.
      Note that because there is only one customErrors section under the 
      <system.web> node, there is no need to use the "xdt:Locator" attribute.

      <customErrors defaultRedirect="GenericError.htm"
        mode="RemoteOnly" xdt:Transform="Replace">
        <error statusCode="500" redirect="InternalError.htm"/>
      </customErrors>
    -->
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

However my published connection string still displays as the following, even when `Live` is selected:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="foo" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" connectionString="[main connection string]" />
</connectionStrings>
```

What possible reasons are there for this happening?

Comment: How are you publishing? Are you using a "Publish Profile"? Depending on your publish "Connection" type (e.g. Web Deploy) you get specific "Settings" allowing you to set the connection string. I am not sure, but I am wondering if perhaps this is set to your main connection string and is taking precedence over your config transform? Might be worth a look at least (uncheck "Use this connection string at runtime"). Other than that, the config file itself looks ok

Comment: @musefan Thanks, I tried doing `xdt:Transform="Replace"` on the `appSettings` and these changes were applied to the rendered config! Therefore it's definetely an issue with the connection string part. However, when I "Preview transform" in VS2012, it does apply the transform

Comment: huh, didn't know you could preview transform, that's pretty cool. Anyway, how are you doing the publish? If the preview works then it must be something else overwriting it after the transform

Comment: @musefan It's a profile publish to a local file system. I'm currently looking around for the "Use this connection string at runtime" option, but no luck so far

Comment: Ah, I don't think "File System" has that option. Only "Web Deploy" and "Web Deploy Package" seem to... back to the thinking board!

Comment: Just had a quick play and it was working at first, but then I switched from "Release" to "Debug" and it was keeping the release transform. It seems you have to switch it each time in the "Settings" section of the "Publish" wizard. Can you confirm this? Also worth double checking you don't have a typo in the `name` of your connectionString - I assume you are not using "foo" in your real application.

Comment: @musefan That's solved it! I was using the 1 profile for both configuration types. I've changed this so each config type has its own profile, and this works fine now. Please feel free to post an answer so I can mark it! Cheers. P.S: Muse are awesome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the problem in this case is assuming that changing the build configuration profile will automatically update your Publish Profile to match - this is not the case.

If you have a single Publish Profile then you will have to manually change the "Settings" > "Publish" > "Configuration" setting each time you make a build, as this is what determine which config transform file is applied.

The recommended way to handle this is to create multiple Publish Profiles - one for each build  configuration. For example, "Debug" and "Release", or in this case "Live" and "UAT". This way you can easily switch between the two profiles during the Publish process.

It is worth noting that there are other benefits to this approach than just managing your transforms. Having different profiles for different builds allows you to specify different targets too. For example, if you use the Web Deploy method you can send the application to different servers depending on your target environment (e.g. Testing or production)

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem, where the applied transformations would be the ones from "Debug", not from my "Test" configuration.  I solved it by manually editing some files.  I am not sure which ones were wrong, and how they got wrong, but this is how I solved it.

I changed the .sln from "Debug":

```
    {96...D2A}.Test|Any CPU.ActiveCfg = Debug|Any CPU
    {96...D2A}.Test|Any CPU.Build.0 = Debug|Any CPU
    {96...D2A}.Test|Mixed Platforms.ActiveCfg = Debug|Any CPU
    {96...D2A}.Test|Mixed Platforms.Build.0 = Debug|Any CPU
    {96...D2A}.Test|x86.ActiveCfg = Debug|Any CPU
```

to "Test":

```
    {96...D2A}.Test|Any CPU.ActiveCfg = Test|Any CPU
    {96...D2A}.Test|Any CPU.Build.0 = Test|Any CPU
    {96...D2A}.Test|Mixed Platforms.ActiveCfg = Test|Any CPU
    {96...D2A}.Test|Mixed Platforms.Build.0 = Test|Any CPU
    {96...D2A}.Test|x86.ActiveCfg = Test|Any CPU
```

I changed the Test-configuration in the .csproj from:

```
<PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Test|AnyCPU'">
  <DebugSymbols>true</DebugSymbols>
  <OutputPath>bin\</OutputPath>
  <DefineConstants>DEBUG;TRACE</DefineConstants>
  <DebugType>full</DebugType>
  <PlatformTarget>AnyCPU</PlatformTarget>
  <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
  <CodeAnalysisRuleSet>MinimumRecommendedRules.ruleset</CodeAnalysisRuleSet>
</PropertyGroup>
```

to (I am not sure what all these removed parameters mean/imply):

```
<PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Test|AnyCPU'">
  <OutputPath>bin\</OutputPath>
  <DefineConstants>DEBUG;TRACE</DefineConstants>
</PropertyGroup>
```

I changed the Web.Test.config in the .csproj from:

```
<None Include="Web.Test.config">
  <DependentUpon>Web.config</DependentUpon>
</None>
```

To:

```
<Content Include="Web.Test.config">
  <DependentUpon>Web.config</DependentUpon>
</Content>
```

Comment: changing <None> to <Content> worked for me, although it does copy the files to the deployed site, which isn't great